# How to set up Travis Rspec for testing read replicas accessed in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rspec, travis-ci

I have a rails application that accesses two databases: a read replica and it's own database configured through a standard `database.yml` file.

There are certain models that access the read replica, and I use `establish_connection` to dynamically switch over to the replica:

```rb
class MyReadReplicaDbBase < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.abstract_class = true
  establish_connection READ_REPLICA_DB
end

class User < MyReadReplicaDbBase
end
```

Actual environments work well with this setup, but while testing on travis, I need to set up two databases using an approach like this:

```
language: ruby

cache: bundler

rvm:
  - 2.5.1

services:
  - docker
  - redis-server

env:
  global:
    - DB_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost/travis_ci_test
    - READ_REPLICA_DB_URL=postgres://postgres@localhost/travis_ci_read_replica_test


# https://github.com/travis-ci/travis-ci/issues/9624#issuecomment-389537036
before_install:
  - sudo sed -i -e '/local.*peer/s/postgres/all/' -e 's/peer\|md5/trust/g' /etc/postgresql/*/main/pg_hba.conf
  - sudo service postgresql restart
  - sleep 1
  - gem update --system
  - gem install bundler

sudo: required
dist: xenial
addons:
  postgresql: "10"
  apt:
    packages:
      - postgresql-10
      - postgresql-client-10
  env:
    global:
      - PGPORT=5433

before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_read_replica_test' -U postgres


script:
  - bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rspec -f d
```

Is there a standard approach to load the schema in the replica database for testing? Can I run something like the following?

```
rake:db:schema:load --database read_replica_db
```

I understand this won't work because it will pull the default environment to set up that database.

Comment: "Setup": noun. "Set up": verb phrase.

Answer (score 0):

So I got it working using a Personal access token and copying the schema over using this script

```rb
#load_read_replica_schema.rb
#!/home/travis/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.1/bin/ruby

def install_gems()
  system('gem install pg')
  system('gem install activerecord -v=5.2.2')
end

def get_read_replica_schema_file
  require 'active_record'
  require 'active_record/tasks/database_tasks'
  require 'active_record/tasks/postgresql_database_tasks'

  curl_command = "curl -s https://#{ENV['PERSONAL_ACCESS_TOKEN']}@raw.githubusercontent.com/<owner>/<repo>/master/db/schema.rb -o read_replica_schema.rb"
  system(curl_command)


   ActiveRecord::Tasks::DatabaseTasks.load_schema('postgres://postgres:@localhost/travis_ci_read_replica_test', :ruby, 'read_replica_schema.rb', :test)
end


install_gems()
get_read_replica_schema_file()
```

Similarly updated the script to run on the travis.yaml script with a script

```
before_script:
  - cp config/database.yml.travis config/database.yml
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_test;' -U postgres
  - psql -c 'create database travis_ci_read_replica_test' -U postgres

script:
  - ./load_read_replica_api_schema.rb
  - bundle exec rails db:migrate RAILS_ENV=test
  - bundle exec rspec -f d
```